# Amazon web service to get purchase data

Tags: web-services, amazon

Is there a web service (either one of Amazon's own or a third-party) that will let me pull my purchase data from Amazon into my own site? This is strictly for personal use; I only want to get data associated with my own Amazon account. I'm currently working in PHP, so would need a PHP API.

**EDIT:**
Just to make it clear, I'm looking for my own purchase history, not data from my seller account. I'd also consider a feed of info from my media library section. Given that there's an option to share those items, I'm assuming there's some kind of programmatic hook into it.

Comment: Emmy,
Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Sneaky... you moved this. To respond: I did find a way to do what I needed to, but it's messy and nowhere near ideal. See answer.

Comment: I have thought of another way to tackle this. Since I have enabled email alerts to my mail account for all transactions, i am gonna use google APIs to access my emails, and then filter the purchases for amazon.in as a sender. After that it's just restructuring of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a way to do this, although it's not ideal - it requires downloading, uploading, etc. any time changes are made (i.e. if I buy something new and want it to be available to my site.) It also includes items you haven't actually purchased (wish lists.) Right now it's not a huge issue; this was a development exercise for me and I don't particularly care if the information is totally up-to-date now that my database is populated.

Here's what I had to do:

1. Install the [Amazon Library Exporter](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ancmofphhhhoafhaiaenodkljacpgbfc) extension in Chrome;
2. Go to https://kindle.amazon.com/ and click My Books, then All Books;
3. On each individual page (can only do one page at a time, not the entire list) click the extension icon in the URL bar;
4. In the popup window that comes up, click the Google Books button (you must have a google account);
5. After completing steps 3 and 4 for every page of my Amazon books, go to [books.google.com](http://books.google.com) and click My Library;
6. Your books will have filtered into one of several lists, depending on the status of them in Amazon (wish list items show up under To Read, the others may be under Reading Now or Have Read.);
7. Click on each list, and under Options choose Export as XML.

From there, I used an XSLt stylesheet and some PHP code to transform the XML into a SQL file, which I then imported into mySQL via phpMyAdmin.

(It didn't really take as long as it sounds like it would once I figured out all the steps. But it isn't a one-step, click and you're done solution, and as I mentioned, it also is a one-time thing - if you want updates you need to redo all of the steps. I haven't found a way to filter out the books that I already exported from Amazon and only pull in new ones since there's no way to sort the list by date.)

Answer (score 4):

You can manually request an "Order History Report" [here](https://www.amazon.com/gp/b2b/reports) that contains all of your orders to date. Use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to automate the process.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The OP is over two years old, and I don't really need to do this anymore, but that's good info to have. How exactly did you find that report? When I click back one level in the breadcrumbs (to just Your Orders) there's nothing anywhere to indicate that there are reports available. Also the PhantomJS library looks like a really interesting project. I'm definitely going to explore that for other uses.

Comment: Yes, the OP is old, but it is also still one of the top hits on Google for this problem :)

Comment: See updated answer for a screenshot of the report link.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't bother going all the way back to account.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Amazon does give you some info on tracking your item stats. log into your account on seller central and then click on site metrics and reports and the reports tab.

Also this article has some services which might be of use I haven't checked them out personally.

http://askville.amazon.com/tools-Amazon-sellers-sales-statistics-item-sell/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=7110230

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for seller statistics - I want my own purchase history (i.e. things I've bought from Amazon.)

Comment: Interesting info. Do you know what extra those 3rd party services give you that Amazon's reports don't? Also, do you know of any that are for general products (e.g CDs and DVDs), not just books?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to Amazon.com

In the upper right hand corner, click on the phrase "Your Account"

In the next screen, click on the button that says: view, modify or track "Your Orders"

At the next screen you may need to enter your user id and password

In the next screen there is a drop down option on the left hand side of the screen. From there you can "show orders" and select as far back as you like.

"Source some person on the internet" (thanks)

Comment: Did you read the original question? I'm looking for a web service that I can access programmatically, not a way to manually look at my purchase history.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggested "Order History Report" link (https://www.amazon.com/gp/b2b/reports). It lets you enter any date range, not just by year. But so far, it always hangs. I just have a personnel account, not business. I hope others try this link.